# Scheduling a task using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to schedule a task " a toast message" to appear in the time chosen by the user, but nothing is showing after that time and i can't see what is wrong in the code. 
That's my code

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        //set The Calendar to to the wanted time!
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        Intent setMsg = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, setMsg, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
}


public class TaskReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "it is working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If there is a better way to schedule such a task please go ahead and introduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yourcomp.yourapp.R;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TestAct extends Activity {

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler{
        private WeakReference<Activity> activityWr;

        public MyHandler(Activity activityMain){
            activityWr = new WeakReference<>(activityMain);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
            if (activityWr.get() != null){
                Toast.makeText(activityWr.get(),"Your text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
    private MyHandler mHandler;
    private Future<?> mToastTaskRef;
    private static int NUMBER_OF_CORES =
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
        /**
         * initialize UI & take input from user && call method
         */

    }

    private void showToastAfterUserSpecifiedDelay(int seconds){
        mToastTaskRef = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_CORES).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.sendMessage(new Message());
            }
        },       /**initial delay*/60
                ,/**time*/seconds
                ,/**time unit*/ TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    private void stopToastTask(){
        if (mToastTaskRef != null && !mToastTaskRef.isCancelled() && !mToastTaskRef.isDone()){
            mToastTaskRef.cancel(true); //tru -- >interrupt even if it's running
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I give the function showToastAfterUserSpecifiedDelay a specific time  int like "60", it doesn't show up actually after 60 sec but it just keep showing from 0 sec..

Comment: @kendhia I've changed the initial delay to 60 seconds. It's visible in the code

Comment: What i wanted is that the delayed time should be the parameter given to the function, so changing the initial delay to be "seconds" and time to be like 60 should make thingsright

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code Instead of `manager.setExact` method as follows:

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: interval would be any value for millisecond e.g 3000 for 3 seconds

Comment: Can you please explain why you made that change ?